# 2015-03-05 15:35:35 IST HINT No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Tags: postgresql

I have facing problem in the below function of postgres, I have tried by looking many examples like this, which has been uploaded by many others but still I dint find the solution. Please help me out.

I know the below function is lengthy. Thanks

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION adt_transfer_patient(in_hospital_id integer, in_reg_no character varying(50), in_admt_id numeric, in_transfer_type character varying(25), in_release_cause character varying(1), in_user_id character varying(50), in_new_dept_id integer, in_new_unit_id integer, in_new_ward_id integer, in_consultant integer, in_icd character varying(50), in_icd_desc character varying(50))
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
temp_dept_id integer;
temp_unit_id integer;
temp_ward_id integer;
return_int integer;
temp_bed_id integer;
temp_present_position character varying;
temp_is_blocked integer;
max_diagnos_id integer;
tmp_bedno text;
tmp_ward text;
temp_node_ward_id integer;
tmp_tot_record integer;
tmp_int_var integer;
icdcode character varying(25);
disease_remark character varying(200);

BEGIN
temp_is_blocked=0;
--Present Department,Unit,Ward and Bed
SELECT dept_id INTO temp_dept_id FROM department_admission WHERE hospital_id=in_hospital_id AND ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id AND release_date IS NULL ORDER BY admission_date DESC limit 1;
SELECT unit_id INTO temp_unit_id FROM unit_admission WHERE hospital_id=in_hospital_id AND ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id AND release_date IS NULL;
SELECT ward_id INTO temp_ward_id FROM ward_admission WHERE hospital_id=in_hospital_id AND ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id AND release_date IS NULL
ORDER BY admission_date DESC limit 1;
SELECT COALESCE(bedid,'0') INTO temp_bed_id FROM bed_occupancy  WHERE hospital_id=in_hospital_id AND ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id AND releasedate IS NULL;
--Tranfer Department
IF in_transfer_type = 'D' THEN
    UPDATE department_admission SET release_date=current_timestamp,release_cause=in_release_cause,userid=in_user_id
    WHERE reg_no=in_reg_no AND ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id AND hospital_id=in_hospital_id AND  release_date IS NULL;

    INSERT INTO department_admission(hospital_id,reg_no,ipd_admission_id,dept_id,admission_date,admission_time,userid)
    VALUES (in_hospital_id,in_reg_no,in_admt_id,in_new_dept_id,current_timestamp,current_time,in_user_id);


END IF;
--Transfer Unit
IF in_transfer_type = 'D' OR in_transfer_type = 'U' THEN

    UPDATE unit_admission SET release_date=current_timestamp,release_cause=in_release_cause,userid=in_user_id
    WHERE reg_no=in_reg_no AND ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id AND hospital_id=in_hospital_id AND release_date IS NULL;

    INSERT INTO unit_admission(hospital_id,reg_no,ipd_admission_id,unit_id,admission_date,admission_time,userid)
    VALUES (in_hospital_id,in_reg_no,in_admt_id,in_new_unit_id,current_timestamp,current_time,in_user_id);


END IF;

--Transfer Ward

IF in_transfer_type = 'D' OR in_transfer_type = 'U' OR in_transfer_type = 'W' THEN

    UPDATE ward_admission SET release_date=current_timestamp,release_cause=in_release_cause,userid=in_user_id
    WHERE reg_no=in_reg_no AND ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id AND hospital_id=in_hospital_id AND release_date IS NULL;

    IF in_transfer_type = 'W' THEN

    INSERT INTO ward_admission(hospital_id,reg_no,ipd_admission_id,ward_id,admission_date,admission_time,userid,dept_id,unit_id)
    VALUES (in_hospital_id,in_reg_no,in_admt_id,in_new_ward_id,current_timestamp,current_time,in_user_id,temp_dept_id,temp_unit_id);

    ELSIF in_transfer_type = 'U' THEN
     INSERT INTO ward_admission(hospital_id,reg_no,ipd_admission_id,ward_id,admission_date,admission_time,userid,dept_id,unit_id)
     VALUES (in_hospital_id,in_reg_no,in_admt_id,in_new_ward_id,current_timestamp,current_time,in_user_id,temp_dept_id,in_new_unit_id);
    ELSIF in_transfer_type = 'D' THEN
         INSERT INTO ward_admission(hospital_id,reg_no,ipd_admission_id,ward_id,admission_date,admission_time,userid,dept_id,unit_id)
     VALUES (in_hospital_id,in_reg_no,in_admt_id,in_new_ward_id,current_timestamp,current_time,in_user_id,in_new_dept_id,in_new_unit_id);
    END IF;


END IF;

--Tranfer Bed
    UPDATE bed_occupancy SET releasedate=current_timestamp,userid=in_user_id
    WHERE reg_no=in_reg_no AND ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id AND hospital_id=in_hospital_id AND releasedate IS NULL;

   --SELECT COUNT(*) into temp_is_blocked FROM mas_link_ward,ward_admission where mas_link_ward.parent_ward_id=ward_admission.ward_id 
    --and mas_link_ward.node_ward_id=temp_ward_id and ward_admission.release_date is null and abs(extract(epoch from current_timestamp - admission_date)/20000)>48;


 --  SELECT COUNT(*) into temp_is_blocked FROM mas_link_ward,ward_admission where mas_link_ward.node_ward_id=ward_admission.ward_id     and mas_link_ward.parent_ward_id=temp_ward_id and mas_link_ward.parent_dept_id=temp_dept_id and ward_admission.release_date is null and abs(extract(epoch from current_timestamp - admission_date)/20000)>48;

 --SELECT node_ward_id into temp_node_ward_id FROM mas_link_ward,ward_admission where mas_link_ward.node_ward_id=ward_admission.ward_id and mas_link_ward.parent_ward_id=temp_ward_id and mas_link_ward.parent_dept_id=temp_dept_id and ward_admission.release_date is null and abs(extract(epoch from current_timestamp - admission_date)/20000)>48;


 if temp_is_blocked is null then
   temp_is_blocked=0;
 end if;

    IF temp_is_blocked>0 THEN
    UPDATE mas_bed SET status='B' WHERE bedid=temp_bed_id AND hospital_id=in_hospital_id;
       IF in_hospital_id=4 THEN

--*** insert record into notification table ***
   select bedno into tmp_bedno from mas_bed where bedid=temp_bed_id;
   select ward_name into tmp_ward from mas_ward where ward_id=temp_node_ward_id;




    INSERT INTO table_notification(sl_no, notification, group_type, ward_id, dept_id, unit_id, employee_id,seen) 

SELECT (SELECT COALESCE(max(sl_no),0) FROM table_notification)+row_number() OVER(),'Bed No'||tmp_bedno||' of ward '||tmp_ward||' is blocked','W',temp_node_ward_id,0,0,uid,0 FROM config.user_ward_mapping
 WHERE ward_id=temp_node_ward_id; 
 END IF;

    ELSE 
    UPDATE mas_bed SET status='A' WHERE bedid=temp_bed_id AND hospital_id=in_hospital_id;
    END IF;


    IF in_new_bed_id != 0 THEN

        INSERT INTO bed_occupancy(hospital_id,reg_no,ipd_admission_id,bedid,occupancydate,occupied,userid,entrytime)
        VALUES (in_hospital_id,in_reg_no,in_admt_id,in_new_bed_id,current_timestamp,'O',in_user_id,current_time);
        UPDATE mas_bed SET status='O' WHERE bedid=in_new_bed_id AND hospital_id=in_hospital_id;        

-- Set present Position 
temp_present_position='~IPD^'||get_department_name(in_hospital_id,in_new_dept_id)||'^'||get_unit_name(in_hospital_id,in_new_unit_id)||'^'||get_ward_name(in_hospital_id,in_new_ward_id)||'^'||get_bed_no(in_hospital_id,in_new_bed_id); 

    END IF;
        IF in_new_bed_id = 0 THEN
                INSERT INTO bed_occupancy(hospital_id,reg_no,ipd_admission_id,bedid,occupancydate,occupied,userid,entrytime,transfer_to_floor)
        VALUES (in_hospital_id,in_reg_no,in_admt_id,-1,current_timestamp,'O',in_user_id,current_time,'Y');


        --UPDATE bed_occupancy SET transfer_to_floor='Y' WHERE reg_no=in_reg_no AND ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id AND hospital_id=in_hospital_id; 


    END IF;

--Entry in Patient transfer log

--NOTE: Valid Entry Against Trasnfer Type only
INSERT INTO patient_transfer_log(hospital_id, reg_no, ipd_admission_id, transfer_type, transfer_date,transfer_time, from_department_id, to_department_id, from_unit_id,
            to_unit_id, from_ward_id, to_ward_id, from_bed_id, to_bed_id,consultant_id)
    VALUES (in_hospital_id,in_reg_no,in_admt_id,in_transfer_type,current_timestamp,current_time,temp_dept_id,in_new_dept_id,temp_unit_id,
            in_new_unit_id,temp_ward_id,in_new_ward_id,temp_bed_id,in_new_bed_id,in_consultant);


IF in_transfer_type = 'D' THEN
-- Set present Position 
temp_present_position='~IPD^'||get_department_name(in_hospital_id,in_new_dept_id)||'^'||get_unit_name(in_hospital_id,in_new_unit_id)||'^'||get_ward_name(in_hospital_id,in_new_ward_id)||'^'||get_bed_no(in_hospital_id,in_new_bed_id);    
ELSIF  in_transfer_type = 'U' THEN    
-- Set present Position 
temp_present_position='~IPD^'||get_department_name(in_hospital_id,temp_dept_id)||'^'||get_unit_name(in_hospital_id,in_new_unit_id)||'^'||get_ward_name(in_hospital_id,in_new_ward_id)||'^'||get_bed_no(in_hospital_id,in_new_bed_id);   

ELSIF  in_transfer_type = 'W' THEN     
-- Set present Position 
temp_present_position='~IPD^'||get_department_name(in_hospital_id,temp_dept_id)||'^'||get_unit_name(in_hospital_id,temp_unit_id)||'^'||get_ward_name(in_hospital_id,in_new_ward_id)||'^'||get_bed_no(in_hospital_id,in_new_bed_id); 
ELSIF  in_transfer_type = 'B' THEN     
-- Set present Position 
temp_present_position='~IPD^'||get_department_name(in_hospital_id,temp_dept_id)||'^'||get_unit_name(in_hospital_id,temp_unit_id)||'^'||get_ward_name(in_hospital_id,temp_ward_id)||'^'||get_bed_no(in_hospital_id,in_new_bed_id); 

END IF;         


UPDATE patient_detail SET present_position=COALESCE(present_position,' ^ ^ ^ ^')||temp_present_position,ward_id=in_new_ward_id,ward_entry_date=current_timestamp,bedid=in_new_bed_id,occupancydate=current_timestamp
 WHERE reg_no=in_reg_no AND
 hospital_id=in_hospital_id AND ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id;
 IF in_hospital_id=4 and in_icd<>'' THEN 
 select count(*) into tmp_tot_record from (select unnest(string_to_array(in_icd, ',')))tbl;


 tmp_int_var = 1;
 WHILE tmp_int_var <= tmp_tot_record LOOP
              SELECT split_part(in_icd, ',', tmp_int_var) INTO icdcode;
              SELECT split_part(in_icd_desc, ',', tmp_int_var) INTO disease_remark;
            IF icdcode IS NOT NULL THEN
              Select  coalesce(max(slno),0)+1 into max_diagnos_id FROM tran_diagnosis_log              where reg_no=in_reg_no;

              INSERT INTO tran_diagnosis(
            reg_no, slno,icd_o,remarks,
            provisional_final, doctor_id, hospital_id, ipd_admission_no, entry_source,entry_date)

            VALUES (in_reg_no, max_diagnos_id,icdcode,disease_remark,'Final', in_user_id::integer,            in_hospital_id, in_admt_id,'TRANSFER',current_timestamp); 

            INSERT INTO tran_diagnosis_log(
            reg_no, slno,icd_o,remarks,
            provisional_final, doctor_id, hospital_id, ipd_admission_no, entry_source,entry_date)

            VALUES (in_reg_no, max_diagnos_id,icdcode,disease_remark,'Final', in_user_id::integer,              in_hospital_id, in_admt_id,'TRANSFER',current_timestamp); 

           tmp_int_var = tmp_int_var+1;
           END IF;
            END LOOP;

/**--update ipd_patient_admission_detail set disease=in_pro_diagnos where hospital_id=in_hospital_id and reg_no=in_reg_no and ipd_admission_id=in_admt_id;
Select  coalesce(max(slno),0)+1 into max_diagnos_id FROM tran_diagnosis_log where reg_no=in_reg_no;

if max_diagnos_id=1 THEN 
INSERT INTO tran_diagnosis(
            reg_no, slno,
            provisional_final, doctor_id, remarks, hospital_id, ipd_admission_no, entry_source)

    VALUES (in_reg_no, max_diagnos_id,'Provisional', in_user_id::integer, in_pro_diagnos, in_hospital_id, in_admt_id,'TRANSFER'); 

INSERT INTO tran_diagnosis_log(
            reg_no, slno,
            provisional_final, doctor_id, remarks, hospital_id, ipd_admission_no, entry_source)

    VALUES (in_reg_no, max_diagnos_id,'Provisional', in_user_id::integer, in_pro_diagnos, in_hospital_id, in_admt_id,'TRANSFER'); 

END IF;
if max_diagnos_id>1 THEN 

INSERT INTO tran_diagnosis_log(
            reg_no, slno,
            provisional_final, doctor_id, remarks, hospital_id, ipd_admission_no, entry_source)

    VALUES (in_reg_no, max_diagnos_id,'Provisional', in_user_id::integer, in_pro_diagnos, in_hospital_id, in_admt_id,'TRANSFER');

END IF; **/



END IF;







RETURN 1;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
```

Comment: Do you get the error when creating the function or when calling the function? If you get it when calling it, then how exactly are you calling it? If you get it when creating it, then which line is reported as the error?

Comment: `,admission_date,admission_time,` ... you seem to have separate fields for date and time; while `current_timestamp` is a timestamp (with time zone)